# why Android App auto restart after runtimeException?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

My app run in  two 5.0 android system.

In my develop ,I have a uncaught `RuntimeException`

When meet the exception,My App will auto restart ,

I don't know why my App auto restart? even if I call `System.exit(1)`

this is the log with RuntimException

```html
E/AndroidRuntime(23905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23905): Process: com.oosmart.mainapp, PID: 23905
E/AndroidRuntime(23905): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: devices (code 1): , while compiling: drop table devices
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1655)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.oosmart.mainaplication.db.DBOperation.execute(DBOperation.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.oosmart.mainaplication.db.DevicesDB.dropTable(DevicesDB.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.oosmart.mainaplication.db.DBHelper.DropTable(DBHelper.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.oosmart.mainaplication.fragment.UserCenterFragment.onExitClick(UserCenterFragment.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.oosmart.mainaplication.fragment.UserCenterFragment$$ViewBinder$6.doClick(UserCenterFragment$$ViewBinder.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4806)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19952)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5313)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1116)
E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:809)
```

this is the log with System.exit

```html
I/AndroidRuntime(20479): VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
I/AndroidRuntime(23172): VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
I/Process (24461): java.lang.RuntimeException
```

The Logs I grep with `Runtime`

update:
Even if I call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

The app still restart with a new pid. 
I don't know why I can't fully exit by code .

Comment: Probably because you are not finishing your previous activity and when the new activity creates an exception it closes the current activity and opens the previous. Someone correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yes , I have not finish the previous activity, But `runtime exception` will not crash the app? even if I call `Systme.exit()`

Comment: Show us some code then for more clarification

Comment: you are dropping table which doest exist. so check condition over there.

Comment: the code is normal `Runtime Exception` , I will try post a new  project with the same error in github

Comment: Runtime Exception do crash your application and you are trying to drop the table which don't even exists and even system.exit() don't exit your application. Best practice is to user try catch when you are using any complicated coding

Comment: @user998953 : if you are OK with my answer then please accept and up-vote the answer thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are not finishing your previous activity and when the new activity creates an exception it closes the current activity and opens the previous and Runtime Exception do crash your application and you are trying to drop the table which don't even exists and even system.exit() don't exit your application. Best practice is to user try catch when you are using any complicated coding.
Someone correct me if I am wrong

Comment: `System.exit()` works in first Activity, But  I can't understand ,`Runtime  Exception`  not crash application  or crashed but auto started,if has an previous activity

Answer (score 1):

My all application will restart when it is ERROR, seems it happen in Android Studio. You should try-catch the SQLiteException to stop the crash, after you can call finish() to exit the activity.

Comment: Thank you ， I just confused why my app not full exit, with `runtime exception`  even if I call `kill pid`